# Восстановление байтовой информации (uint8_t) из хекса (hex)

Tags: c++, hex

Для переносимости ключи шифрования представляются из массива `uint8_t` в шестнадцатиричном виде:

```
for(int i = 0; i < KEYSIZE; ++i)
    std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << static_cast<int>(PrivateKey[i]);
```

В силу специфики hex'а, каждый байт информации представляется двумя символами, т.е. из одного байта выходит целых два. Как корректно прочитать стринг с хексом в массив uint8_t, чтобы восстановить оригинальную байтовую информацию?

Убил около пяти часов, пытаясь осуществить задачу в виде `reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(publicKey.c_str())`, пока не *догадался*, что проблема в изложенном выше феномене, а не в каких-то других частях кода. Но с ними, если что, потом ;)

Comment: В каком виде у вас стока hex-ов?

Comment: @avp хранятся в std::string, если вы об этом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, можно воспользоваться [std::from_chars()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <charconv>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "ff01aa00";
    
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); i += 2)
    {
        int val = -256;
        std::from_chars(&str[i], &str[i+2], val, 16);
        std::cout << val << " ";
    }
}
```

[Вывод](https://ideone.com/UFe9Pr):

```
255 1 170 0
```